# Is it possible for an application to exist in both ionic and the regular web?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I started my project on angular 14 (nx), and I want to do this project both in ionic and in the regular web, is it really possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible! That's one of the advantages of Ionic. You can make app builds for Android and iOS, then have a web hosted version as well. Ultimately it's still Angular you're using. One thing to consider is you won't have access to Cordova from the web version, so no push notifications or other native features.

I have found, though, that if I'm using the same branch for both web and app versions, I have to program it to recognize which platform it's on. Then, if it's on web, it'll not use any Cordova features.